# Is it possible to get a "use of uninitialized local variable" warning in Visual Basic?

Tags: c#, vb.net, warnings, variable-declaration

Compare the following snippets:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i;
    Console.Write(i); // yields an error: Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
}
```

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim i As Integer
    Console.Write(i)  ' no warning
End Sub
```

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim s As String
    Console.Write(s)  ' yields a warning: Variable 's' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.
End Sub
```

I like the warning shown in the last example and I'd like to have it in the second example (value type) as well (although the text from the first example would be more appropriate than the one from the third in that case). Is this possible or is this a feature that has been (deliberately) omitted from VB.NET?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict...but string doesnt have a new constructor therefore it probably dont care. What happens when you take out the type...?

Comment: Also the second is safe as int's default to zero as the compiler see's it.

Comment: @436f6465786572: How dare you suggest that I *don't* have Option Strict On by default... ;-)

Comment: Either way it should be replicable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Here's what Microsoft says about it in this closed [feature suggestion](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/621965/use-of-an-unused-local-variable-should-be-at-least-a-compile-time-warning-in-vb-net-as-it-is-in-c) of 2010:

> Receiving warnings when you haven't used one of your locals is indeed valuable and we'd love to add this warning to Visual Basic. However, we must be careful as we introduce new warnings given the number of people who run with "warning-as-error" enabled. While this warning would often indicate a coding error, there may be instances within existing apps where an unused local is benign - left over from a previous version of the method. In these cases, we need to take great care not to break existing codebases when they are moved from one version of the language to the next.

So it seems they won't add this feature due to backward compatility reasons.

Comment: It is possible, I can replicate it in VS2010

Comment: @436f6465786572 Really? Could you prove it with a screenshot?

Comment: @436f6465786572 Your using a reference type in your code, not a value type, so no.